# SSLProtocolException when using HttpsUrlConnection against same server from separate threads

Tags: java, httpsurlconnection

Been scratching my head for the best part of 2 days now. Any pointers or wild guesses are welcome at this point.

I have 2 separate webapps running in Tomcat 8.5 making client https connections to different urls at the same server (a Sales Force sandbox).

Whatever of them to get loaded first works alright but the second one fails on connect with

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, 5
```

The noted `5` above can be randomly `2`, `4`, `3` or `1`. Also message can be `Unknown record type...`

There seems to be some kind of shared resource under the hood as both webapps work correctly on their own.
Seems to me as if my client was trying to initiate a new handshake while the server is reusing a previously open connection??

Calling `disconnect()` on the connections does not make any difference and neither does sending a `"Connect: close"` header.
Also tried consumption of all response data and closing streams without success.

Exception is always thrown at `conn.getOutputStream()`.

Here's what one thread does:

```
final HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(reqBytes.length));
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
try (OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
     os.write(reqBytes);
     os.flush();
}

final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     b.append(line).append(NEWLINE);
}
conn.disconnect();
```

Here's the other:

```
URL url = new URL(reportingUrl);
byte[] reqBytes = report.toString(2).getBytes("UTF-8");
final HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(reqBytes.length));
 conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
 conn.setDoOutput(true);
 try (OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
     os.write(reqBytes);
     os.flush();
 }
 InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 while (in.read(buffer) > -1) {}
 conn.disconnect();
```

Finally here's some customization I'm doing at server start:

```
TrustManager[] tlsTrustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new ReloadableX509TrustManager(null, null)};
 SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.1");
 ctx.init(null, tlsTrustManagers, null);
 ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
 ctx.init(null, tlsTrustManagers, null);
 SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);
```

`ReloadableX509TrustManager` just imports any unknown certificate into de current truststore and reloads itself. I've been using it for years without issue. At any rate it only does something special each fist time ever it sees a new untrusted certificate.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer the question, yes, that should work. It did not in my old jdk 8 update 102 but it certainly does in an version 8 update 172 one.

I don't really understand the "only second instance affected behavior" but it was certainly related to unlimited strength policy files not present. Setting those up solved the issue.

Now this is not a issue since [jdk 8 update 161](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u161-relnotes-4021379.html#JDK-8170157).

Thanks anyway